# Stata: Combine table command with ttest and output latex

Tags: stata

For regression output, I usually use a combination of `eststo` to store estimations, `estadd` to add the R2 and additional tests, then `estab` to output the lot.

I need to do the same with the `table` command. I need the mean, median and N for a variable across three `by variables` and would like to add stars for the result of a ttest==1 on the mean and signtest==1 on the median. I have three `by variables`, so I've been using `table` to collate the mean, median and N, which I'm calling like the following pseudo-code:

```
sysuse auto,clear
table foreign rep78 , ///
    contents(mean price median price n price) format(%9.2f)
ttest price==1, by(foreign rep78)
signtest price=1, by(foreign rep78)
```

I've tried `esttab` and `estpost` to no avail. I've also looked at `tabstat`, `tablemat` and `summarize` as alternatives to `table`, but they don't allow three `by variables`.

How can I create this table, add the stars for the `ttest` and `signtest` p-values and output the full table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point in your question seems to be producing a LaTeX table. However, you show "pseudo-code", that looks pretty much like Stata code, with the caveat that it is illegal.

In particular, for the `ttest` you can only have one variable in the `by()` option. But notice that `ttest` allows **also** the `by:` prefix (you can use both, in fact). Their reasons-to-be are different. On the other hand, `signtest` **does not** allow a `by()` option but it does allow the `by:` prefix. So you should probably clarify what you want to do *before* creating the table.

If you are trying to use the `by:` prefix in both cases and afterwards produce a table, you can create a *grouping* variable, and put the commands in a loop. In this way, you can try tabulating the saved results for each group using the ESTOUT module (by Ben Jann in SSC). Something like:

```
*clear all
set more off

sysuse auto
keep price foreign rep78

* create group variable
egen grou = group(foreign rep78)

* tests by group
forvalues i = 1/8 {
    ttest price == 1 if grou == `i'
    signtest price = 1 if grou == `i'

    *<complete with estout syntax>
}
```

See `help by`, `help egen` (the *group* function), `help estout` and `help saved results`.

Comment: The issue is firstly to (1) display the results of a `table` command in the GUI in Stata, (2) display the results of a ttest and signtest on each group in the GUI in Stata and (3) collate the results of these two in a table which has the 'right' layout for me. The latex output is trivial after that, I hope! If estout is the right command, I'll follow that up.

Comment: See also `help statsby`.